# Get string from starting index to end from char Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have an object with a char Array; where the first 5 bytes(char in C++) are additional data and everything afterwards is a string message.

So my question is how can I get a string from starting index 5 way up to the last byte?

I know there is memccpy, but it requires an ending char, which I can't know beforehand.
I am aware there is a string object in C++, but the idea is to send back and forth a byte array which contains the data and message. So in a sense I serialize and deserialize back and forth.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
Packet * Packet::create(byte const data[])
{
    //Concat all first 4 byte values to a uint32
    unsigned int length = data[0] << 32 | data[1] << 16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3] << 0;

    //4th element is packet type
    PacketType type = (PacketType)data[4];

    string packetData;

    packetData.clear();
    char * cdata;
    //Check packet data is present
    if(sizeof(data) > 5)
    {
        //string s((char)data);
        //packetData = s.substr(4, s.length() - 4);
        strncat(cdata,data+5,sizeof(data)-5);
        packetData.append(cdata);
    }

    //Create new packet;
    Packet * packet = new Packet(length,type,packetData);

    return packet;
};
```

It won't accept data[] even when I cast it to char. 
The argument isn't a pointer?

Edit::

```
Packet * Packet::create(char const * data)
{
    //Concat all first 4 byte values to a uint32
    unsigned int length = data[0] << 32 | data[1] << 16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3] << 0;

    //4th element is packet type
    PacketType type = (PacketType)data[4];

    //Set packet data, if available
    string packetData = (sizeof(data) > 5) ? string(data+5):"";

    Packet * packet = new Packet(length,type,packetData);
    return packet;
};
```

I still have to test this, but I had to use char, how do I use my own typedef in this situation?

Also what is the difference between 
"char * data"
and
"char data[]"

I thought arrays and pointers are one and the same thing.

Comment: Use: `strncpy` or `strcpy`, and arrays are contiguous in memory so just use, `(source + 5)` as source buffer, that ensures you copy from 5th character in your source char array.

Comment: If you can change your consumer to accept a begin/end pair, you don't need to make any copies at all...

Comment: `sizeof(data)` is wrong. It'll give you the size of the pointer, not the length of the c-string it points to. Use `strlen(data)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned "know there is memccpy, but it requires an ending char, which I can't know beforehand". Does that means that your serialized data doesn't have neither the size of the data nor a delimiter? Without that how do you expect 
        "string packetData = (sizeof(data) > 5) ? string(data+5):"";"
to work?
For the serialization you could send the size of your data as well in the header. Then use the simple memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) with `charArray + 5` as source parameter.

You should also know of [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) which gives you the string's length [might be needed to allocate the `char[]`, if there is not known upper bound for it].

**EDIT:** code snap:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
  char in[] = "XXXXXqwerty";
  //dynamic allocation using strlen() if you don't have upper bound for in
  char* out = new char[strlen(in) - 4]; 
  strcpy(out,in+5);
  cout << out;
  delete[] out;
  return 0;
}
```